# Wave number at different refractive index

Tags: waves, electric-fields, refraction

If I have different refractive index surfaces (as shown at the picture below) can I say that:
$\overrightarrow{E}_{n=1}=Ae^{i(k_{1}z-wt)}\hat{x} $

$\overrightarrow{E}_{n=n_{c}}=Be^{i(k_{1}n_{c}z-wt)}\hat{x} $

$\overrightarrow{E}_{n=n}=Ce^{i(k_{1}nz-wt)}\hat{x} $

 Meaning that $k_{3}=k_{1}n_{c}z$ and $k_{5}=k_{1}nz$ because the electric field does not change it’s direction (always $\hat{x}$) while traveling through this surfaces?

[image]

Comment: you can say that, but it doesn't have anything to do with electric field boundary conditions.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean please?